# UIScrollView changes its height when displaying

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView which I have created in Interface Builder. In that scroll view, I am adding UITableView programmatically. I fixed the height and width of the scrollview using Autolayout and set its content size programmatically. I think scroll view is not supposed to change its actual height while displaying but it is appearing small. When I logged the height of the scrollview it is giving 128. But it should not.

Here is the code:

```
    self.tableScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width)*(totalpages),self.tableScrollView.frame.size.height);
[self.tableScrollView setDelegate:self];
for(int i=0;i<totalpages;i++)
{
    NSLog(@"scroll view %f",self.tableScrollView.frame.size.height);
    CGRect tableFrame = CGRectMake((([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width)*i),0,([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width),self.tableScrollView.frame.size.height);
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc]init];
    tableView.frame=tableFrame;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.tag=i;
    tableView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    //tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    //tableView.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins=NO;
    //ELIMINATE THE EXTRA SEPARATOR LINES AT THE END OF THE TABLEVIEW
    //[tableView setTableFooterView:[UIView new]];
    [self.tableScrollView addSubview:tableView];
}
```

Please help.

I found that its height is changed according to the tableview. But Why?

Comment: do u have any other elements than table view in your scroll view ?

Comment: @Mr.T No, Just table view. I am trying to enter table view  horizontally.

Comment: if it is just table view y do u use another scrollview ? to scroll the tableview horizontally ?

Comment: It is not only a single table view. Number of tableviews depend on the condition. and it is getting scrolled and everything is fine. The only thing is scrollview should appear at least of height 400 but it is appearing small. There is nothing to do with horizontal scrolling.

Comment: You should not be adding UITableView to UIScrollViews, as it's already a subclass of UIScrollView. Can you clarify what you mean by 'number of tableviews'? Usually only one tableview is necessary per screen, and multiple sections are used if the content needs to be grouped differently.

Comment: I want to make something like view pager in Android